# NLP how to go beyond simple intent finding--using context and targeting objects

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, spacy

Edit: Apologies if this isn't the proper space for this kind of question. Would appreciate if you can please point me to a better forum

I'm manually applying NLP rules to a chatbot.

Currently, I've a simple set of rules--actions that follow certain trigger words.
Ex: **"Create the match on saturday."**

This has been working for relatively simple phrases like the above example, where I would expect words like "create" and appoint it as an `action` word, expect "match" then appoint it as an `object` entity; "saturday" as a `time`, etc.

When I try to expand the scope of what the bot can handle, it becomes more complicated. Here's an example of something I'm trying to handle:

**"Update the memo title of the match on saturday to 'Game Day'."**

I'm not sure how to move forward.

I considered manually expanding(expecting) the entities, then trying a method where I still parse for `action` words, but if a certain threshold of varying `objects` is passed, then I execute a subset of that `action`.

For example: `update` will obviously signal an action, but the addition of "memo", "title", "'Game day'", signals a subset of the action as there's more to this than a simpler "create match". Then, checking the additional objects like "title" against a predetermined set of entities will narrow down the intent to `update` + `title`.

I see many holes in this logic, esp. as the complexity even slightly increases.

This led me to the field of dependency parsing.
But upon looking into dep. parsing, I wonder if this is something feasible in manual implementation.

I'll be using python code, it won't be deep learning based.

What do you think of the basic rule-based method I've outlined? Is it something that sounds workable for a domain-specific bot?

Should I be looking into using NLP libraries offered in Python such as NLTK or spaCy and use their features? My concern with using these features such as spaCy's dependency parser was that it was overkill, or too much added complexity for handling my domain specific tasks. Furthermore, and likely because I haven't yet seen effective use of it in another project, I guess I have doubts the practicality of dependency parsers outside of academia or research.

Edit: Apologies if this isn't the proper space for this kind of question. Would appreciate if you can please point me in the right direction

Comment: I think it depends on how narrow your domain scope is, and whether a general user knows what trigger words to use. I would imagine user input to a chatbot to be messy and require a lot of rules and maintenance to update.

Comment: How would it change as domain scope becomes narrower? Domain is quite specific and the similar set of trigger words will be used by most users.

Comment: I was just thinking a broader domain like healthcare (let's say) vs a narrower domain like toe surgery would narrow the scope of questions people might ask. From there it's a matter of knowing what people do ask. I would make a text classifier to try and map text input to some defined set of actions. You could train it with your domain knowledge and generate text of what people might input. Better to use real input if you have it.